# Disable closing of a certain WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I'd like to know if there's a possible solution (I hope there is) to my problem. I have two forms, the Login Form and the Main Form. I'd like to know if there's a way to disable closing of the Main Form and only allow closing when I sign out (which redirects the user back to the Login Form) and only allow closing when Login Form is active. Sorry for my bad english.

I tried using the event below, yes it stops me from closing the main form but when I signed-out it did the same to my Login Form which I didn't want to happen. Is there any way to do this?

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{ 
  e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: You can keep a flag somewhere which indicates whether the user has signed out. Set the flag to `true` when the user signed out. Then in `Form1_Closing` event `e.Cancel = flag;`.

Comment: I'm sorry but this "flag" is new to me (Beginner Level). I'd love to hear if you can explain to me how can I apply this to my forms. Thank you in advance Sir.

Comment: It can be  `public static bool SignedOut;` in `Program` class in `Program.cs` and `e.Cancel = Program.SignedOut;`

Comment: I see, thank you Sir. I'll try to test it out.

Comment: Problem solved Sir. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are using LoginForm like dialog (ShowDialog), Use DialogResult.Ok only when user logs successful

```
....

private voif logoutButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _logged = false;
}

.....

private void loginButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginForm _loginForm = new LoginForm();
    if(_loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
    {
        _logged = true;
    }
}

......

private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(!_logged)
       e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Not really but I'll try this one out too. Thanks for the answer sir.